# How to use SQLite group_concat(X, Y) to create a single column from a JOIN?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Forgive me if I'm not phrasing this question correctly.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have two tables joined on a string column containing a GUID. **Table 1** contains everything concerning my data object, while **Table 2** contains a string column that I need to link to the record from **Table 1**. For every record in **Table 1**, there are **1..n** records in **Table 2**.  My current SQLite statement using an **INNER JOIN** is returning n records for each record in **Table 1**, and this doesn't work for my needs.  I want to get back just 1 record for each record in **Table 1**.

However, the trick is that I still want to see all of those string values from Table 2, with the strings concatenated as "*Value 1; Value 2; Value 3; etc*".

I've tried using the **group_concat(X, Y)** function as follows:

```
SELECT o.ObservationGuid, o.ObservationID, o.ObservationParentTypeGuid, 
    o.ObservationTypeGuid, o.Name, o.ObservationParentName, o.GrowthStageGuid, 
    o.MorphologyTypeGuid, o.LifespanGuid, o.OrganismTypeGuid, o.ScientificName, 
    o.AgXID, o.AgGatewayID, o.Genus, o.Family, o.TaxonomicalOrder, o.Class, 
    o.Division, o.Kingdom, o.FavorableConditions, o.DescriptionSymptoms, 
    group_concat(oa.Name, '; ') 
FROM Observation o 
INNER JOIN ObservationAlias oa ON oa.ObservationGuid = o.ObservationGuid 
WHERE ObservationTypeGuid = '{E3149781-2423-4F15-8599-CB320E871284}' 
GROUP BY o.ObservationGuid COLLATE NOCASE
```

But this results in no records returned at all.  Next, I tried removing the **GROUP BY** clause:

```
SELECT o.ObservationGuid, o.ObservationID, o.ObservationParentTypeGuid, 
    o.ObservationTypeGuid, o.Name, o.ObservationParentName, o.GrowthStageGuid, 
    o.MorphologyTypeGuid, o.LifespanGuid, o.OrganismTypeGuid, o.ScientificName, 
    o.AgXID, o.AgGatewayID, o.Genus, o.Family, o.TaxonomicalOrder, o.Class, 
    o.Division, o.Kingdom, o.FavorableConditions, o.DescriptionSymptoms, 
    group_concat(oa.Name, '; ') 
FROM Observation o 
INNER JOIN ObservationAlias oa ON oa.ObservationGuid = o.ObservationGuid 
WHERE ObservationTypeGuid = '{E3149781-2423-4F15-8599-CB320E871284}' 
COLLATE NOCASE
```

This returns 1 record, consisting of the first matching record from **Table 1** plus the oa.Name field containing the string value of EVERY record in **Table 2** in the format "*Value 1; Value 2; Value 3; etc*"

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what does it give you when you don't use contact_group?

Comment: have you tried group_concat(distinct oa.Name SEPARATOR '; ') ?

Comment: Why are you using COLLATE NOCASE?

Comment: When I leave out concat_group() I get the same result set as my first and third examples above.  distinct keyword makes no difference.  I am using COLLATE NOCASE because sometimes the guid values are in lower case, other times upper.  I have no control over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong, and it is borderline embarrassing.  COLLATE NOCASE must precede the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT o.ObservationGuid, o.ObservationID, o.ObservationParentTypeGuid, 
    o.ObservationTypeGuid, o.Name, o.ObservationParentName, o.GrowthStageGuid, 
    o.MorphologyTypeGuid, o.LifespanGuid, o.OrganismTypeGuid, o.ScientificName, 
    o.AgXID, o.AgGatewayID, o.Genus, o.Family, o.TaxonomicalOrder, o.Class, 
    o.Division, o.Kingdom, o.FavorableConditions, o.DescriptionSymptoms, 
    group_concat(oa.Name, '; ') 
FROM Observation o 
INNER JOIN ObservationAlias oa ON oa.ObservationGuid = o.ObservationGuid 
WHERE ObservationTypeGuid = '{E3149781-2423-4F15-8599-CB320E871284}' 
COLLATE NOCASE
GROUP BY o.ObservationGuid
```

That's it, and now the query returns only unique records from **Table 1** including every value from the **Name** column in **Table 2** concatenated into one value in my result set.